# int cannot be converted to Node

Tags: java

I'm getting this error:

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Node

Why am I getting this kind of error?

```
public void insertItem(int e)
{
  if(e<head.getItem())
  {
     addFirst(e);
  }
  else if(count==1)
  {
     addLast(e);
  }
  else
  {
     Node newNode = new Node(e);
     Node prev = head;
     Node p = prev.getItem();

     while(p!=null)
     {
        if(e<p.getItem())
        {
           newNode.setLink(p);
           prev.setLink(newNode);
           p = p.getLink();
           prev = prev.getLink();
        }
      }
   }
}



public class Node {
 private Node link;
 private int item;
 public Node(int item, Node link) {
  setLink(link);
  setItem(item);
 }
 public Node(int item) {
  this(item, null);
 }
 public Node() {
   this(0, null);
  } //empty node
 public void setLink(Node link) {
  if (link != null) this.link = link;
 }
 public void setItem(int item) {
  this.item = item;
 }
 public Node getLink() {
  return link;
 }
 public int getItem() {
  return item;
 }
 public String toString() {
  return item + "";
 }
}
```

I was using getItem() from another class here it is:

```
public class Node
{
    private Node link;
    private int item;

    public Node(int item, Node link)
    {
        setLink(link);
        setItem(item);
    }

    public Node(int item)
    {
        this(item, null);
    }

    public Node()
    {
        this(0, null);
    }
//empty node public void setLink(Node link){ if(link != null) this.link = link; } public void setItem(int item)
// {this.item = item;} public Node getLink(){return link;} public int getItem(){return item;} public String toString(){return item+ "";} }
```

Comment: Post you getItem() method. You are using : `e<head.getItem()` and `Node p = prev.getItem()`. Both cannot be right!!!

Comment: It seems that your `getItem()` method returns an Integer value and not a node.

Comment: Im getting an error at this line:
Node p = prev.getItem();

Comment: I was using getItem() from another class
here it is:

`public class Node{
   private Node link;
   private int item;
   
   public Node(int item,Node link){ setLink(link); setItem(item);}
   public Node(int item){ this(item,null);}
   public Node(){this(0,null);}//empty node
   public void setLink(Node link){
    if(link != null)
      this.link = link;
   }
   
   public void setItem(int item){this.item = item;}
   public Node getLink(){return link;}
   public int getItem(){return item;}
   public String toString(){return item+ "";}

}`

Answer (score 0):

As you can clearly see, `Node#getItem` returns `int` value not a `Node` value.

So when you are trying write : `Node p = prev.getItem();` it is showing you the error.

Maybe what you need is : `Node p = prev.getLink();`

Comment: now I'm getting another error which is java.lang.NullPointerException at this line `if(e<head.getItem())`